# I am quite new to Swagger tool. Does any one know how to use Swagger Editor tool in Intellij Idea

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I am quite new to Swagger tool. Does any one know how to use Swagger Editor tool in Intellij Idea and not the online editor format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [intellij-swagger](https://github.com/zalando/intellij-swagger) by [zalando](https://github.com/zalando) to easily edit Swagger specification files inside IntelliJ IDEA.